# How to efficiently add objects to ManyToManyFields of multiple objects Django python?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to efficiently add objects to ManyToManyFields of multiple objects?

```
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        shops = MyShop.objects.all()
        for shop in shops:
        month_invoice = shop.shop_order.annotate(year=TruncYear('created'), month=TruncMonth('created')).values(
        'year', 'month', 'shop_id'
    ).annotate(total=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        (F('item_comission') / 100.00) * (F('price') * F('quantity')), output_field=DecimalField())),
    ).order_by('month')
    for kv in month_invoice:
        a = ShopInvoice.objects.create(shop_id=kv['shop_id'], year=kv['year'], month=kv['month'], total=kv['total'])
        test = shop.shop_order.filter(created__month=kv['month'].month, created__year=kv['year'].year)
        for t in test:
            a.items.add(t.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe `.add()` method accepts multiple objects to add. I have not looked at this Django source code, but would expect that if there was any optimisation possible, it would have been done. So try

```
a.items.add( *[ t.id for t in test ] )
```

If you have Django Debug Toolbar installed you can very rapidly see whether it's optimized (typically one DB operation instead of N = len(test) )